# How to select text value from a variable div id tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

```
<div id="Modal<%= index %>">
     <div>
      <input type="text" id="textvalue">
    </div> 
</div>
```

In the above code I need to get value of text field but the problem coming is the div id is variable according to index i.e it may be 'Modal0' or 'Modal1' or 'Modal"n"' depending on value of index. So, if i write $(#textvalue).val() then it is always giving the text entered in id 'Modal0'. What will be solution for this? And the big issue is that I can not  use 'Modal0' or 'Modal1' ... id because that is generated dynamically.

Comment: Under what event do you need to get the value of the input, and how does the element that raises that event relate to the `div` in the HTML?

Comment: if there are multiple modals, then you input id has to be unique as well.

Comment: you can use `index` method in JS, like we are using in `.each` loop. Guy's Please read the que first then answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The scenario is that i have 3 buttons and after clicking on any button the div id changes according to the index and that button will open a new pop up window where i can enter the text and submit  it. So,when i click on submit button at that time I need the value of text entered in text box.

Comment: Could you please post a more complete sample of your HTML that includes the buttons and the other `div id="ModalX"` elements

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Posting full code is difficult but i can post some more thing.
<a href=#"Modal<%= index %>"<img src="button.png"></a>
<div id="Modal<%= index %>">
     <div>
      <input type="text" id="textvalue">
    </div> 
</div>
So, there are three identical button on the page and if i click button1 then an input box will open and for that div id will be 'Modal0' and if i click on second button then again the input box will open but this time div id will be 'Modal1' and so on.

Comment: In that case just use `next()` to get the related div in the click handler for the `a` element

Answer (score 0):

you can use closest jquery function like that make dive id is different.
closest will fetch the parent tag.

$(diveid).closest("diveid").inoutid.val();

Comment: I have check other people solution but that is not proper if your code is dynamic please give the div id Modal_[dynamic number] and give same class name of input type then after use closest function to get textbox value

Answer (score 0):

You should include the parent div in the query as well, for example:

```
$("#Modal0 input").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should select the div you´re looking for , then find it's text-input

```
$('#Modal0').find('#textvalue').val();
$('#Modal1').find('#textvalue').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but if the clicking of buttons will only affect the ID of *the same container* `div` of the `input.textvalue` element then this will do the trick:

```
$('div[id^=Modal] #textvalue').val());
```

DEMO:

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    const ID = $(this).attr('href')
    const counterID = ID.substring(ID.length-1);
    const targetID = $('div[id^="Modal"]').attr('id');
    $('div[id^="Modal"]').attr('id', 'Modal'+(counterID-1));
    console.log('DIV ID:', 'Modal'+(counterID-1));
  });
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){
   console.log('DIV ID: ' + $('div[id^=Modal]').attr('id'), ' ,TEXT VAL: ' + $('div[id^=Modal] #textvalue').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#Modal1">Modal 1</a> 
<a href="#Modal2">Modal 2</a> 
<a href="#Modal3">Modal 3</a> 
<div id="Modal"> 
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="textvalue"> 
  </div> 
  <button>submit</button>
</div>
```